# List with tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm new to Python and have some questions about lists and tuples.
I've got a list consisting of tuples with sentences and wordclass-tags. This is one element in my list:

```
[('It', 'PPS'), ('says', 'VBZ'), ('that', 'CS'), ('``', '``'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'AT'), ('event', 'NN'), ('Congress', 'NP'), ('does', 'DOZ'), ('provide', 'VB'), ('this', 'DT'), ('increase', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('federal', 'JJ'), ('funds', 'NNS'), ("''", "''"), (',', ','), ('the', 'AT'), ('State', 'NN-TL'), ('Board', 'NN-TL'), ('of', 'IN-TL'), ('Education', 'NN-TL'), ('should', 'MD'), ('be', 'BE'), ('directed', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('``', '``'), ('give', 'VB'), ('priority', 'NN'), ("''", "''"), ('to', 'IN'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('pay', 'NN'), ('raises', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')]
```

As you can see each word has a wordclass-tag. How can I search after word + wordclass in my list? F.ex. if I would like to see if the element about contains the word "federal" attached to the wordclass-tag "JJ" ?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're really trying here -- but it seems like a different data structure would make your life a lot easier.  Maybe a dict which holds a list?  Then you can map wordclasses to a list of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if you have the word 'federal' tagged with 'JJ' on your list:

```
your_list = [('It', 'PPS'), ('says', 'VBZ'), ('that', 'CS'), ('``', '``'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'AT'), ('event', 'NN'), ('Congress', 'NP'), ('does', 'DOZ'), ('provide', 'VB'), ('this', 'DT'), ('increase', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('federal', 'JJ'), ('funds', 'NNS'), ("''", "''"), (',', ','), ('the', 'AT'), ('State', 'NN-TL'), ('Board', 'NN-TL'), ('of', 'IN-TL'), ('Education', 'NN-TL'), ('should', 'MD'), ('be', 'BE'), ('directed', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('``', '``'), ('give', 'VB'), ('priority', 'NN'), ("''", "''"), ('to', 'IN'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('pay', 'NN'), ('raises', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')]
print ('federal', 'JJ') in your_list
```

Using list comprehension syntax you can do more interesting things with your list, for example see all tags of all occurrences of a word:

```
print " ".join([wordclass for word, wordclass in your_list if word == 'federal'])
```

It's good to build some functions doing generic operations on the data structure you work with, like checking if it contains a word or tag:

```
def hasWord(l, word):
    for w, wordclass in l:
        if w == word:
            return True
    return False

def hasTag(l, tag):
    for w, wordclass in l:
        if wordclass == tag:
            return True
    return False

if hasTag(your_list, 'JJ'): print your_list
```

To answer your question in the comments:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    if ('federal', 'JJ') in sentence:
        print sentence
```

Comment: This almost does the trick. But how can I use it to find whole elements witch matches a specific word,wordclass?
I would like to print the whole sentence if it contains the specific word,wordclass ?

Comment: Almost I think, but it have to be a combination. I have to search through each element (sentence) in the list for a combination of word and wordclass, and then print the entire element (sentence) if it is a match.

Comment: So, my list is "brown_sents", witch is a list where each sentence is a list of "word,wordclass".

Comment: Your list contains a parsed sentence, therefore you can do it like this: if ('federal', 'JJ') in your_list: print your_list

Comment: My list is a list containing a list (a list containing sentences, containing words,wordclass

Comment: See the updated answer. Is it Ok now? I mean, your example list wasn't a list of sentences, where each sentence was a list of tuples, but if this is the case, then the last bit of code should satisfy you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a set instead. Then you can use the `in` operator efficiently:

```
wlist = set([('It', 'PPS'), ('says', 'VBZ'), ('that', 'CS'), ('``', '``'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'AT'), ('event', 'NN'), ('Congress', 'NP'), ('does', 'DOZ'), ('provide', 'VB'), ('this', 'DT'), ('increase', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('federal', 'JJ'), ('funds', 'NNS'), ("''", "''"), (',', ','), ('the', 'AT'), ('State', 'NN-TL'), ('Board', 'NN-TL'), ('of', 'IN-TL'), ('Education', 'NN-TL'), ('should', 'MD'), ('be', 'BE'), ('directed', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('``', '``'), ('give', 'VB'), ('priority', 'NN'), ("''", "''"), ('to', 'IN'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('pay', 'NN'), ('raises', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')])

print ('federal', 'JJ') in wlist # prints True
```

Comment: Why can't you use `in` for list?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that.. I've imported the Brown corpus with sentences, so I've got a very large list with a lot of elements as i posted above. I'm trying to do something like this: 
'    
for sets in brown_sents:
        counter=0
        if any("house" in s for s in sets):
            if any("IN-TL" in r for r in sets):
                if(teller < 1):
                    return sets
                    counter+=1
'

The problem is that the first "for" finds the correct sentence, but the second one searches through the entire sentence for the wordclass-tag, not only the word..

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: You can, but it's much slower (`O(n)`) because the list has to iterate through all the items, whereas the set does a hash lookup (`O(1)`).

Comment: @piokuc: If you do more than one lookup, the creation of the set will be worth it.

Comment: Two possible pitfalls here: the set will collapse all instances of unique pairs, so you won't get an accurate count of pairs.  Second, it will force you to search for pairs as pairs: set won't spead up for, say, all the items with a given tag.  For that the list comprehension answer may be easier, although slower.  That said, it is the fastest pure-python way to find if there's a given nugget in a big corpus

Answer (score 0):

My first approach was:

```
def find_tuple(input, l):
    for (e1, e2) in l:
        if e1==input[0] and e2==input[1]:
            return True
    return False
```

It is straight forward but static and only suitable to your problem.
A more general but equal approach:

```
def my_any(iterable, input, func):
    for element in iterable:
        if func(element, input):
            return True
    return False

input = ("federal","JJ")
l = [("It", "PPS"),("federal","JJ")]
print(my_any(l, input, lambda x, y: x[0]==y[0] and x[1]==y[1]))
```

Pass in a lambda function to decide for yourself what boolean matching you prefer.
And an easy approach to this would be this:

```
input = ("federal","JJ")
l = [("It", "PPS"),("federal","JJ")]
if input in l:
    print("True")
```

If you would be more specific on the problem you like to solve it would be easier to give a concrete advice. (i.e.: What is your returning type: Boolean/String/Tuple..?) Hope this helps.

Cheers!